# PHP problem sorting values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an API returning a kind of date formatted as follow: 
2010_m1 for Jan 2010
2010_m2 for Feb 2010
...
2010_m12 for Dec 2010

I have all the dates in an array, and if I use the method sort, it will sort it like:
2010_m1, 2010_m10, 2010_m11, 2010_m12, 2010_m2, 2010_m3, ...

How could I sort it the 'correct way', ie:
2010_m1, 2010_m2, 2010_m3, ... , 2010_m10, 2010_m11, 2010_m12

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called [natural sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php):  `natsort()` is the PHP function for it.